# vaadin shows wrong class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying Vaadin. I developed two classes. In both classes, I extended its servlet with the code similar to below:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = <CurrentClassName>.class)
 public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

When I run the second class, it always show UI from first one. I tried restarting Tomcat but its still the same.
e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/hms/servlet/com.test.ui.TestClass2$Servlet
```

I tried creating a new class and when I run that, even that shows the UI of first one.

Please help to understand and resolve the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create class MyUIProvider that extends basic UIProvider and override getUIClass method.

For instance:

```
public class MyUIProvider extends UIProvider
{
    @Override
    public Class extends UI> getUIClass(UIClassSelectionEvent event)
    {
        // imlement UI class choosing logic here
        return MyUI.class;
    }
```

Than add init-param to your VaadinServlet in web.xml:

```
 ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>VAADIN</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UIProvider</param-name>
            <param-value>your.package.MyUIProvider</param-value>
            <description>Your custom UIProvider</description>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
 ...
```

Comment: Hi, Do you mean I need to do this for every single UI class I create? Moreover, the class already extend from 'UI' class of Vaadin.

Comment: Create as many UI classes as you need. Next, implement the logic in getUIClass method under what conditions which UI class will be returned.